# Dynamic Array Stack Corruption

Tags: ethereum, solidity

This contract appears to be a game offering 1/16 odds at the balance of the contract. However, when running the code in a debugger it appears as if the 'secretNumber' variable is being overwritten before it is used.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract CryptoRoulette {

    uint256 private secretNumber;
    uint256 public lastPlayed;
    uint256 public betPrice = 0.1 ether;
    address public ownerAddr;

    struct Game {
        address player;
        uint256 number;
    }
    Game[] public gamesPlayed;

    function CryptoRoulette() public {
        ownerAddr = msg.sender;
        shuffle();
    }

    function shuffle() internal {
        // initialize secretNumber with a value between 0 and 15
        secretNumber = uint8(sha3(now, block.blockhash(block.number-1))) % 16;
    }

    function play(uint256 number) payable public {
        require(msg.value >= betPrice && number < 16);

        Game game;
        game.player = msg.sender;
        game.number = number;
        gamesPlayed.push(game);

        if (number == secretNumber) {
            // win!
            msg.sender.transfer(this.balance);
        }

        shuffle();
        lastPlayed = now;
    }

    function kill() public {
        if (msg.sender == ownerAddr && now > lastPlayed + 1 days) {
            suicide(msg.sender);
        }
    }

    function() public payable { }
}
```

The way secretNumber is updated, it should always be less than 16
`secretNumber = uint8(sha3(now, block.blockhash(block.number-1))) % 16;`

This debugger output shows that during execution of `if (number == secretNumber) {` the value of secretNumber has been updated to, oddly enough, the callers address (msg.sender).

```
`
(243) PUSH1 0x00
  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006898f82b
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000143
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (top)

40:         if (number == secretNumber) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^

debug(develop:0x98cacf83...)> i

CryptoRoulette.sol | 0xbd2c938b9f6bfc1a66368d08cb44dc3eb2ae27be:

40:         if (number == secretNumber) {
                ^^^^^^

debug(develop:0x98cacf83...)> p

CryptoRoulette.sol | 0xbd2c938b9f6bfc1a66368d08cb44dc3eb2ae27be:

(245) DUP3
  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006898f82b
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000143
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  000000000000000000000000627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57 (top)

40:         if (number == secretNumber) {
                ^^^^^^
```

My guess is that the storage access before the condition is causing the stack to be corrupted somehow.

Is this a known vulnerability? Can someone please explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue when attempting to create a local reference without specifying the correct storage location.

From the [Solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-is-the-memory-keyword-what-does-it-do):

> There are defaults for the storage location depending on which type of variable it concerns:
>
> - state variables are always in storage
> - function arguments are in memory by default
> - **local variables of struct, array or mapping type reference storage by default**
> - local variables of value type (i.e. neither array, nor struct nor mapping) are stored in the stack

The bolded comment indicates that the line `Game game;` defaults to storage. If you don't initialize a storage variable, it will point to storage slot 0 by default. The end result is when you make a change to `game` (with `game.player = msg.sender;`), it will write the value out to the first slot, which will be whatever the first variable is in your contract (in this case, `secretNumber`).

The correct way to write this is to use `Game memory game;`. The compiler will give you a warning if you omit the `memory` keyword for this exact reason.